# How to apply css class to a component element when it's created by router-outlet?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have DOM that looks something like this:

```
<app>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <project>...</project>
</app>
```

where `project` element is inserted by the router.

How do I add a class to this element?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Assuming you always want the class applied to this component, you can use [`host`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html) in your component metadata:

```
@Component({
  selector:'project',
  host: {
      class:'classYouWantApplied'
  }
})
```

Resulting in:

```
<app>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <project class="classYouWantApplied">...</project>
</app>
```

Comment: what if you don't? doing `<router-outlet class="...">...` doesn't work :/

Comment: what if I want to apply the class to all routed components?

Comment: to clarify: after doing this you must add the style to style.css... at least for me, it would not work by putting it in the parent or child.

Comment: @SunilGarg (this is a really old, I know) but see my answer below to see how to apply this to all components.

Answer (score 25):

use the `adjacent sibling selector` and the `*` wildcard to select the element immediately following the `router-outlet`

**styles.css**

```
router-outlet + * {
  /* your css */
}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know Angular scopes the elements with a `[_nghost_c1]`-like attribute, like `router-outlet + *[_nghost_c1]`. This is also added to my css (I am compiling scss, maybe that's the reason), and it does not get applied to the following element that is scoped in another way.

Comment: You can use something like `::ng-deep router-outlet.router-flex + * { display: flex; flex: 1 1 auto; flex-direction: column }` and define it in the component. AND DON'T ANYBODY DARE SAY ITS DEPRECATED.

Comment: Very clever! However, in my case it did not work perfectly, because I am using animation transitions between routes. During the transition, there are two components siblings of the ```<router-outlet>```. The incoming and the outgoing. To solve that, simply replace the '+' by a '~'. That is ```router-outlet ~ *```.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

The key is [/deep/](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#-deep-) keyword:

```
    :host /deep/ router-outlet + project {
        display: block;
        border: 10px solid black;
    }
```

This works without any extra configurations.

`:host /deep/ router-outlet + *` for whatever component dynamically created by Angular Router.

### Edited 2018/3/5:

Since [Angular 4.3.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#430-2017-07-14) made `/deep/` deprecated, its suggested alternative is `::ng-deep`. And there were a [long discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867) about this.

Comment: Looks like `/deep/` is deprecated. Per this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17867), `::ng-deep` might be it's replacement for now.

Comment: @mfink Thank you. I modified my answer.

Comment: `::ng-deep` is now also deprecated (v8.0.0)

Comment: please update answer for different versions of angular support.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a `HostBinding`, which is effectively the same as using the `host` property that has already been mentioned, although that method throws a TSLint error with default listing rules.

In your component on which you want to apply a class:

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Host (optional for typing) } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class GiveMeAClassComponent {
    @HostBinding('class.some-class') someClass: Host = true;
    ...
}
```

And then in your root `styles.scss` file, you can add the following:

```
.some-class {
    // Styles in here will now be applied to your GiveMeAClassComponent at a root level
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the adjacent sibling selector

```
router-outlet + project { ... }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

but only if @drewmoore's approach doesn't apply.

Comment: it won't work unless you turn off style encapsulation.

Comment: what do you mean, @MarcinKról ?

Comment: With emulated view encapsulation, Angular scopes the sibling selector to the attribute applied to the router-outlet. As a result, the sibling isn't styled.

Answer (score 5):

```
<app>
  <div class="your css class">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</app>
```

This works for me

Comment: This doesn't work, the added element from the router still exists and will mess up any flex you want to use for example.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, Angular 6 recommends me to use @HostBindings and @HostListeners instead of the host property:

```
export class ProjectComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') classes = 'classYouWantApplied';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

since router injects the component after the the router-outler element,
if we would like to style all injected component with the same set of rules the folowing rule is can be helpful.

the css "+" operator select the first sibling element of a certain type, while asterisk (*) is used as a wild card to select any 1st sibling of router-outlet

```css
router-outlet + * {
  // your rules
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example?

Comment: ... and explain how this code answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add a class conditionally, you can add it programmatically from the component:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elemRef: ElementRef) {
  if(someCondition){
    renderer.addClass(elemRef.nativeElement, 'myClass');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it helped to wrap the router-outlet into another container.

```
<div class="classYouWantApplied">
  <router-outlet>
</div>
```

Like this you could apply the class to the surrounding container.

Comment: This is the correct answer, why nobody did not upvoted it?

Answer (score 1):

I created a `RouterOutletHelperDirective` which can be modified as necessary.

Your use-case may be different but for me :

- I needed to set a default set of classes on each router-outlet generated item
- I needed to *prevent* this default based on certain conditions, such as `ActivatedRoute` data.

You use it like this (the class is optional):

```
<router-outlet routerOutletHelper
               [routerOutletHelperClass]="'blue-border'"></router-outlet>
```

Then create the directive, add and export it to your app module.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterOutlet } from "@angular/router";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet[routerOutletHelper]'
})
export class RouterOutletHelperDirective
{
    constructor(private routerOutlet: RouterOutlet,
                private element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
                private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    subscription = new Subscription();

    @Input('routerOutletHelperClass')
    customClassName: string | undefined;

    ngOnInit() 
    {
        this.subscription.add(this.routerOutlet.activateEvents.subscribe((_evt: any) => {

            // find the component element that was just added
            const componentElement = this.element.nativeElement.nextSibling;

            // add a custom class
            if (this.customClassName) 
            {
                this.renderer.addClass(componentElement, this.customClassName);
            }

            // add my default classes, unless the activated route data 
            // (specified in module routing file) has { addDefaultClasses: false }
            if (this.routerOutlet.activatedRouteData && this.routerOutlet.activatedRouteData.addDefaultClasses !== false)
            {
                // these are my application's default classes (material / theming)
                // (an additional data parameter could be 'darkTheme: boolean')
                this.renderer.addClass(componentElement, 'mat-typography');
                this.renderer.addClass(componentElement, 'rr-theme-light');
            }
        }));
    }

    ngOnDestroy()
    {    
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: this no longer works with ivy because the new node is added after the existing node whereas before it was added before

Answer (score 0):

Add host class name which will add a class to the component then use adjacent to target the element.

```
@Component({
  selector:'project',
  host: {
      class:'Project-wrapper'
  }
})
```

now use CSS adjacent with angular

```
::ng-deep to target it:
::ng-deep .Project-wrapper {}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, let's say in your app component you have a
`<router-outlet ></router-outlet>`

inside this router-outlet you have a route component called
`<app-product-detail></app-product-detail>`

and you want to change the view of  in the app.component.html.

first inside the  the component `<app-product-detail>` add this snippet:

````
@Component({


selector: 'app-product-detail',
  host: {
    class:'Project-wrapper'
},
  templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.css']
})```
````

class= 'could be any name'

inside app.component.css you add this snippet below:

```
    ::ng-deep .Project-wrapper { 
width: 85%;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the deprecation of `::ng-deep` in Angular, the proper way to use the solution provided in [@Val's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43538081/8316374) is to set the style in a CSS not bind to a specific component.

Usually, you have in your angular.json file a list of styles declared as follows:

```json
 "projects": {
    "n9-skeleton-ng-cli": {
      "root": "",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "styles": [
              "src/app/app.module.scss"
            ]
          }
       }
    }
```

In one of these styles files, use a selector that will target that router specifically and add the sibling selector.

For instance, to not target every router-outlet in the application, you can add a class on the targeted ones `.router-styled` , then target it: in `src/app/app.module.scss`

```css
router-outlet.router-styled + * {
    /* your css */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know it's late.

I created this directive to allow you to set (static) or bind (dynamic) classes to each component that is injected by Angular next to the `router-outlet` element:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-router-outlet-class

Please upvote my [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/49483) if you **DO** think it's necessary to have such a built-in functionality.