# call child component method from parent component in angular

Tags: angular, angular9

when I click on the about ceo link on the dashboard component it should trigger load click function. about ceo component loading on dashboard component as in router-outlet

```html
    // Dashboard component html (parent component)

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="menu">
               <a href="#" routerLink="aboutceo" (click)="Clickload()">About CEO</a>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
    // dashboard component ts (parent component)

    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    
      @ViewChild(AboutceoComponent, {static:true}) 
      private aboutceo: AboutceoComponent;
    
      constructor(private router:Router) {}
    
      Clickload(){
        this.aboutceo.loadClick();
      }
    }
```

```js
    // aboutceo component ts (child component)

    export class AboutceoComponent implements OnInit {
    
      loadclick(){
        alert("welcome");
      }
    }
```

i tried using viewchild but its not working

Comment: You parent component template doesn't contain a reference to the child component. You have a routerLink, which is for routing, not referencing a child.

Comment: @BrandonTaylor in app.routing.ts file the aboutceo component path is in childrens of dashboard component. about ceo component is loading with in dashboard component router-outlet.

Comment: Routing is completely different than a component reference. ViewChild/Children requires that the component(s) are actually present in the parent component, not rendered as part of a router outlet.

Comment: in this case what we can do ? @BrandonTaylor

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I haven't had to handle that use case before. You might have to first access the router outlet, then see if you can access its children. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587507/angular-how-to-get-component-instance-of-router-outlet

Comment: @BrandonTaylor it is working with (activate) attribute in router-outlet, thanks

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working