# CSS Centre element in Angular Router element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, web

I have tried a lot already and searched many pages but I can't seem to center align it:

[image: See app photo]

```
router-outlet ~ * {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.main{
    margin: 20px;
}
```

The structure is like this:

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
  <div class="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Comment: why did you use this selector ? `router-outlet ~ * ` ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You are trying to align "it", but what is "it" ? Align in which way and where?

Comment: Router-outlet is not customizable template element, you can achieve this using another layer after router-outlet. But you can simply customize your main class. I also recommend you to examine this SO topic, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645811/5955138

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[CSS Flex Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** to align items to center.

You can't center the `router-outlet` by using the `router-outlet` tag name in the css, Because router-outlet is not customizable template element. Instead of using the `router-outlet` tag name, try wrapping it with a `div` and apply the flex box styles to the div's class.

In the below example the wrapper div has a class called `.main`.

`justify-content: center` is used to align the items to the center.

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content-center;
   width: 90%;
}

<mat-sidenav-content>
  <div class="main">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bear Nithi. How did you know that we have to use align content and justify align? Can you elaborate a bit! Thanks again :)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ this cheat sheet for flexbox will teach more than what i can expalin. it's a good material for flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is described a bit vague, I will try to answer it anyway. Please comment if I got you wrong.

As I understood, you try to horizontally align a sibling container of an `router-outlet`-tag.

**Why it is not working?**
The router outlet has no defined `display` property. Therefore it's width and height is `0px` and you are not able to center another container according to a `0px` width element.

**Solution**

```
router-outlet {
  display: block;
}
```

This enables you to do the follwing:

```
<div> <!-- some outer element -->
  <router-outlet>
  <div #center-me>CENTER ME</div>
</div>
```

```
router-outlet ~ #center-me {
  margin: auto; /*  example if center-me is a block-level element */
}
```

It is possible, even I wouldn't recomend you to do so.Styling according to an wrapper elemnt would possibly be the better aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using bootstraps Flex attributes, they make your life much easier and allow the websites to be very responsive in regards to resolution and different screen sizes.

Useful Link - [Bootstrap Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

An example of how to centre something -

```html
<div class="d-flex w-100>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-centre justify-content-between">
    Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
```